# Как в БД сделать поиск по всем схемам?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

В БД есть много схем, каждая из них может содержать таблицу X. Нужно посчитать количество записей с условием например `X.name = "a"` по всем схемам. Как лучше это сделать? Про реализацию на конкретном языке не спрашиваю, просто общий алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

В MS SQL Server можно обратиться к системным представлениям и получить список таблиц, так же можно приджоинить схемы. Ну а дальше просто считаем количество уникальных строк:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Кол-во таблиц"
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
            s."name" AS "Схема",
            o."name" AS "Таблица"
    FROM sys.objects    AS o
    JOIN sys.schemas    AS s ON o.SCHEMA_ID = s.SCHEMA_ID
    WHERE o."name" = 'TableName'
) AS subquery
```

Уверен, что такие представления есть везде, остаётся нагуглить их названия, если у тебя не MS SQL.